# Change source of video with JS

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm trying to create a fake- dropdown (ul li list) which lets you choose a different video to play. The new video is then loaded into the background of the page.

http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/

When you click the dropdown it should change to a different video.

I started with the source being on the dropdown link:

```
<ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                  <li><a href="images/data/cycling.webm">Cycling | Emirates Arena</a></li>
                  <li><a href="images/data/swimming.webm">Aquatics | Royal Commonwealth Pool</a></li>
                  <li><a href="images/data/athletics.webm">Athletics | Hampden Park Stadium</a></li>
              </ul>
```

In my JS for the dropdown it changes the source onClick

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(){
    var opt = $(this);

    var videoTarget = $('#bgvid');
    var video = opt.find('a').attr("href");  //GRAB URL OF CLICKED LI
    videoTarget.load(video); //LOAD VIDEO URL IN TO THE TARGET AREA

    obj.val = opt.text();
    obj.index = opt.index();
    obj.placeholder.text('Now playing: ' + obj.val);  });
```

But this doesn't seem to reload the video in the background at all.

Comment: Try setting the target's new SRC *then* loading it

Comment: Can you try 
`obj.src = video;
obj.load();  // Load the new video
obj.play();`

Comment: Could you provided examples of this in code? I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Try Aditya's comment is what I mean

Comment: I'm just not sure where this should be in terms of what code it needs to replace, if it does need to replace any code. Should it replace the videoTarget.load?

Comment: try changing the 'src' attribute of the video and then loading it again...

Comment: Could you please outline this comment using the code given above as I have tried changing it but cannot work out what you mean. It would be more helpful with an example written as a solution, not in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @aditya The example code, if I have put it in the right place (it'd be helpful if you could just provide this as a full answer with the code) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing this:

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(){
    var opt = $(this);

    var videoTarget = $('#bgvid');
    var video = opt.find('a').attr("href");  //GRAB URL OF CLICKED LI

    videoTarget.find('source').attr("src", video​​​​)​; //LOAD VIDEO URL IN TO THE TARGET AREA     
     videoTarget.fadeOut();

     setTimeout(function(){
          videoTarget.fadeIn();
          videoTarget.load()​;

     },300);
    obj.val = opt.text();
    obj.index = opt.index();
    obj.placeholder.text('Now playing: ' + obj.val);  });
```

Comment: This stops my dropdown box from working at all. See: http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/

Comment: This is now fixed however the solution is not correct as it reloads the page? Not just the video? Everything reloads.

Comment: Removed load, then it no longer works. This needs to be a smooth transition? So that none of the content reloads when you select a different video. See my link and you'll notice the transition is jerky and not smooth.

Comment: Error when you try to switch video: Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimeOut is not defined (index):218
(anonymous function) (index):218
v.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
o.handle.u

Comment: Changed. It "works" but the transition still jumps and reloads the page

Comment: Makes it worse. Try selecting "aquatics". Then change to "athletics". All content reloads.